# How to group after unwind using AggregationOperation?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, aggregation

Sample Data,

```
{
  
  "_id": ObjectId('63600a4cb7fa6706d181b2d1')
  "Name": "Himanshu",
  "Job": "CEO",
  "Habits": [
    {
      "habitName": "football",
      "level": 3
    },
    {
      "habitName": "chess",
      "level": 5
    },
    {
      "habitName": "test",
      "level": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Requirement:
To get the record which has Name = Himanshu, And
To filter the Habits array, to get only those objects of array which have level = 5.

What I'm trying,

```
        AggregationOperation main = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("Name").is("Himanshu"));
        AggregationOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("Habits");
        AggregationOperation levelMatch = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("Habits.level").is(5));
        AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("$_id").push("Habits").as("Habits");
        
        Aggregation ag = Aggregation.newAggregation(main, unwind, levelMatch, group);
        System.out.println(ag);
        
        AggregationResults<Pc> res = mg.aggregate(ag, "parent_child", Pc.class);
        
        System.out.println(res.getMappedResults().toString());
```

Output is almost what I want, but it gives `Name=null` & `Job=null`

```
[Pc [_id=63600a4cb7fa6706d181b2d1, Name=null, Job=null, Habits=[HabitsDto [habitName=chess, level=5], HabitsDto [habitName=test, level=5]]]]
```

Desired output,

```
[Pc [_id=63600a4cb7fa6706d181b2d1, Name=Himanshu, Job=CEO, Habits=[HabitsDto [habitName=chess, level=5], HabitsDto [habitName=test, level=5]]]]
```

Probably because I'm not including `Name` &`Job` in group, but I'm not sure how to include that, I tried but not able to get the desired output.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You can use filter: `{$set: {Habits: { $filter: { input: "$Habits", cond: {$eq: ["$$this.level", 5]} } }} }`, There is no need for `$unwind` and `$group`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for the suggestion, but could you please help to convert this query in `AggregationOperation` ? I'm not able to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue about Java

Comment: Okay, no problem, I figured that out, Thanks a lot for your help, I was stuck on this for so long.